# Acquiring Indian Land Conservation Data

Tags: geospatial, environment

I am working on a project which assesses the potential for energy development in India. Where could I acquire data which shows areas where the Indian government would likely not permit development? I can see that there is relevant data available on Bhuvan (https://bhuvan.nrsc.gov.in/bhuvan_links.php#), however I have difficulties interpreting the data availability.

If anyone has any resources for finding this sort of data (conserved lands, national parks, protected lands, etc.), please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps try emailing-- government agencies (at least in the USA) are often quite helpful with providing data that's not online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that data from the [World Database on Protected Areas (WDPA)](https://www.protectedplanet.net/c/world-database-on-protected-areas) from UN Environment and the International Union for Conservation of Nature (IUCN).  The geospatial data for India is available for download as Shapefile or CSV [here](https://www.protectedplanet.net/country/IN).

[image]